# Lighthouse Performance values are different in report vs Profile

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

When running a Lighthouse (e.g. v6) via NPM package, for example:

`lighthouse --view --save-assets https://example.com`

Getting these numbers in the browser:

[image]

Then using *Dev Tools > Performance > Load Profile* to load the saved trace JSON, getting:

[image]

### Question

Largest Contentful Paint 2.3s in the report vs 408.0ms in the profile. How to correlate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lighthouse works as expected.

One would have to check-out the *Simulated throttling*:

[image]

After checked-out clicking *View Trace* will show the actual data in the *Performance* panel.

By default *Simulated throttling* is checked-in, it would run the page without any throttling and **then apply throttling manually to the result**. In this case clicking *View Trace* shows the original (unthrottled) data.